# "Can't locate inc/nph-globals.pl in @INC (@INC contains: ......" ERROR for my PERL site

Tags: perl, xampp

I am setting up perl site on XAMPP local server. I have placed the code at proper place and change first line of all `.pl` and `.cgi` files as per the path. i.e.

`#!"D:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"`

for my case. Still I am getting error like

> Can't locate inc/nph-globals.pl in
>   @INC (@INC contains:
>   D:/xampp/perl/site/lib/
>   D:/xampp/perl/lib
>   D:/xampp/perl/site/lib .
>   D:/xampp/apache) at
>   D:/xampp/htdocs//cgi-bin/webscripts/nph-home.pl
>   line 9.

Please suggest.

Comment: Is there such a file anywhere on your system, and if so where?

Comment: yes. nph-globals.pl file is in D:/xampp/htdocs/MYAPPLICATION/cgi-bin/webscripts/inc folder.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the file is located at

```
D:/xampp/htdocs/cgi-bin/webscripts/inc/nph-globals.pl
```

If so, it doesn't work because your script incorrectly assume the current working directory is set to the directory that contains the executing script, namely

```
D:/xampp/htdocs/cgi-bin/webscripts
```

The following code will address that issue:

```
use lib 'D:/xampp/htdocs/cgi-bin/webscripts';
```

Or generically,

```
use Cwd            qw( realpath );
use File::Basename qw( dirname );

use lib dirname(realpath($0));
```

Comment: file is located at D:/xampp/htdocs/abc/cgi-bin/webscripts/inc/nph-globals.pl

Comment: I am executing nph-home.pl file  . follwing are the first 8 lines of code where code breaks.
`code` #!"D:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe" -I D:\xampp\htdocs\fsbp\cgi-bin\webscripts\inc
use lib 'D:/xampp/htdocs/fsbp/cgi-bin/webscripts/inc';

#debugging - uitcomentarieren waneer niet (meer) nodig
# use CGI::Carp(fatalsToBrowser);
# use Data::Dumper;

chdir('../');
#   libs laden

require 'inc/nph-globals.pl';   `code`

Comment: @bhushan, You added `inc` to what I posted. Go back to what I posted and it will work. Because you added `inc`, it's now looking for `.../inc/inc/nph-globals.pl`

Comment: I have added INC variable by looking into some other posts. When I execute the "http://localhost:8080/MY-APPLICATION/cgi-bin/webscripts/nph-home.pl" then initially it shows proper title in browser i.e page starts working correctly but it gives me error as "Error message: 
Attempt to reload inc/nph-globals.pl aborted. Compilation failed in require at D:/xampp/htdocs/MY-APPLICATION/cgi-bin/webscripts/nph-home.pl line 11. , 
". Where my line no 11 is "require 'inc/nph-globals.pl';" and  nph-globals.pl file resides in "D:/xampp/htdocs/MY-APPLICATION/cgi-bin/inc" folder. Please guide.

Comment: @bhushan, You have the general information you need, and you make it impossible to give the specific code since you keep changing the path. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that on the file that give this error, it cannot locate the file inc/nph-globals.pl. probably in that file, you need to specify something like

```
#!"D:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe" -I <path_to_inc_nph-globals.pl>
```

Comment: file is located at D:/xampp/htdocs/abc/cgi-bin/webscripts/inc/nph-globals.pl – bhushan 

compare with your code..see the difference?

#!"D:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe" -I D:\xampp\htdocs\fsbp\cgi-bin\webscripts\inc

Comment: #!"D:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe" is path of perl installation which we need to add on first line ofg each file and  "D:\xampp\htdocs\fsbp\cgi-bin\webscripts\inc" is path for the file which is used  in following  line of executing file i.e. nph-home.pl -> `code `require 'inc/nph-globals.pl';  `code`

Comment: what i meant was one of the path is called abc and another one is called fsbp.

Comment: no no fsbp is correct. it just application name. its "fsbp" in my case.

Comment: I am executing  hello.cgi then its executing properly. So its sure that I am not missing any PERL configuarations. I have also set  ENV variable "PERL5LIB" with value: "D:\xampp\perl\lib"

Comment: Please reply. I am setting up PERL application first time.

Comment: http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/perl/perl-error-cant-locate-module-in-inc read that and see if it helps you. If you are using linux, that will be easier to fix.

Comment: I am using windows. Installing application XAMPP.

Comment: If you are absolutely *sure* that the perl configuration with xampp is ok, then you should start to look at other aspects. For example, settings such as file permission and some other troubleshooting may help.

Comment: I am working on Windows so file permission issue is not afecting the error. It is causing issue for  "require 'inc/nph-glocals.pl'" statement. Do we need to set up a path somewhere else in Perl?

Comment: http://www.mydigitallife.info/install-setup-and-configure-cgi-and-perl-in-windows-xp/ read on "Enabling CGI in Any Directory"